# Iterate over the rows of a second table to return resultset

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to achieve a SELECT query that takes in consideration the result of a second table, by making combinations, replicating a result. I must follow a certain order to don't get all combinations, using a ORDER column.

To ilustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Until now, I tried to use `SUBSELECT` with `JOIN` to replicate the results based on a second table.

```
SELECT a.table_a_id, b.label_x, b.label_y 
FROM table_a a
JOIN
(
    SELECT label_x, label_y
    FROM table_b
    WHERE b.table_a_id = a.table_a_id
) b
ON b.table_a_id = a.table_a_id
```

But, of course, I cant reference the table_a from inside the `SUBSELECT`.

What should be my next steps for achieving my desired ResultSet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a self join here on the `table_b` table, with the join condition being that the `table_a_id` values match, but `label_y` > `label_x`.

```
SELECT
    b1.table_a_id,
    b1.label_x,
    b2.label_y
FROM table_a a
INNER JOIN table_b b1
    ON b1.table_a_id = a.table_a_id
INNER JOIN table_b b2
    ON b2.table_a_id = b1.table_a_id AND
       b2.label_y > b1.label_x
ORDER BY
    b1.table_a_id,
    b1.label_x,
    b2.label_y;
```

[image: screen capture from demo below]

### Demo

Comment: Sir, that worked like a charm, even replicated to the specificities of my application. Perfect, thank you very much.