# Iterate over the rows of a second table to return resultset with cumulative sum

Tags: sql, oracle

Yesterday, after the help of a SO user @
[Iterate over the rows of a second table to return resultset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58527207/iterate-over-the-rows-of-a-second-table-to-return-resultset/58527374#58527374)
I was able to make a combination of rows with a selfjoin.

After some modifications, to adapt to my implementation, I faced a new challenge that I'm stuck: how to make an aggregate sum of a third column?
My issue is better explained in the image below:

[image: sql]

Based on the code

```
SELECT
    b1.table_a_id,
    b1.label_x,
    b2.label_y
FROM table_a a
INNER JOIN table_b b1
    ON b1.table_a_id = a.table_a_id
INNER JOIN table_b b2
    ON b2.table_a_id = b1.table_a_id AND
       b2.label_y > b1.label_x
ORDER BY
    b1.table_a_id,
    b1.label_x,
    b2.label_y;
```

I was able to acquire the combinations.
What should be the next step to get the cumulative sum based on a third column?
I couldn't think of a solution without using a second service, such as python with pandas, using a cumsum function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate the expected resultset, you would need to join the table with itself with an inequality condition on the `order` column. Then, you can do a window sum:

```
select 
    t1.table_a_id,
    t1.label_x,
    t2.label_y,
    sum(t2.value) over(
        partition by t1.table_a_id, t1.label_x
        order by t1."order", t2."order"
    ) agg_value
from 
table_b t1
inner join table_b t2 
    on  t1.table_a_id = t2.table_a_id
    and t2."order" >= t1."order"
order by t1."order", t2."order"
```

Note: `order` is a reserved word, so it needs to be quoted; if you actual database column has a different name, you can remove the double quotes.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=32b8332a7f0e87eded4ed5110940387d)**:

```
TABLE_A_ID | LABEL_X | LABEL_Y | AGG_VALUE
---------: | :------ | :------ | --------:
         1 | A       | B       |         1
         1 | A       | C       |         3
         1 | A       | D       |         6
         1 | A       | E       |        10
         1 | A       | F       |        15
         1 | B       | C       |         2
         1 | B       | D       |         5
         1 | B       | E       |         9
         1 | B       | F       |        14
         1 | C       | D       |         3
         1 | C       | E       |         7
         1 | C       | F       |        12
         1 | D       | E       |         4
         1 | D       | F       |         9
         1 | E       | F       |         5
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked exactly like I needed, and also thank you for the working fiddle. Really good

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a cumulative sum:

```
SELECT b1.table_a_id, b1.label_x, b2.label_y,
       SUM(b1.value) OVER (PARTITION BY b1.table_a_id, b1.label_x
                           ORDER BY b2.order
                          ) as AGG_VALUE
```

Comment: Exactly as I needed. I suspected that I had to use something similar to the cumsum technique, that I already use in Python/Pandas. Really good, thank you.